# .hide() and .show() in jQuery with strange behaivour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 different blocks of different `<section>`s.
You can choose second only after `<option>` in first block. 
As well as third, only if `<option>` from second is chosen.

Changes from first box works ok.
But in second box everything works only for firs two `<section>`s in third block.

I'm trying to figure out the reason, since functions for both boxes are very similar and my own debugging haven't bring me the victory yet.

http://jsfiddle.net/A1ex5andr/3Lv1f2a8/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var sel2 = '#sel2';
    var sel3 = '#sel3';

    $('#sel1').change(function () {
        var selected = $('#sel1 option:selected').attr('id');
        var target = "#sel2_";
        var sel2New = target + (selected.substr(selected.length-1, 1));

        $(sel2New).show();
        $(sel2).hide();
        sel2 = sel2New;

    });

    $('.sel2').change(function () {
        var selectedMid = $(this).attr('id');
        var target_Middle = (selectedMid.substr(selectedMid.length-1, 1));
        var selected = $(this).find(":selected").attr('id');
        var target = (selected.substr(selected.length-1, 1));
        var sel3New = "#sel3_" + target_Middle + '_' + target ;

        $(sel3New).show();
        $(sel3).hide();
        sel3 = sel3New;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason some of your 3rd level lists are not showing up is because of an ID mismatch.

For example, the following  declaration is correct:

```
<select id="sel3_1_2">
```

The following one is incorrect:

```
<select id="sel_3_1_3">
```

Notice the extra underscore between **sel** and **3**.  If you do a find a replace in your code for **sel_** to **sel**, I believe everything should start working as you expect.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I spent to much time coding )) need a rest.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the IDs on some selects in 3rd block starts with `sel_3*` and in your javascript you're trying to access `sel3*`.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to refactor your code!

```js
var myList = [{
    value: 'A',
    title: 'Value A',
    children: [{
        value: 'a',
        title: 'Small value A',
        children: [
            { value: '1', title: 'Value 1' },
            { value: '2', title: 'Value 2' },
            { value: '3', title: 'Value 3' }
        ]
    },{
        value: 'b',
        title: 'Small value B',
        children: [
            { value: '4', title: 'Value 4' },
            { value: '5', title: 'Value 5' },
            { value: '6', title: 'Value 6' }
        ]
    }]
},{
    value: 'B',
    title: 'Value B',
    children: [{
        value: 'c',
        title: 'Small value C',
        children: [
            { value: '7', title: 'Value 7' },
            { value: '8', title: 'Value 8' },
            { value: '9', title: 'Value 9' }
        ]
    },{
        value: 'd',
        title: 'Small value D',
        children: [
            { value: '10', title: 'Value 10' },
            { value: '11', title: 'Value 11' },
            { value: '12', title: 'Value 12' }
        ]
    }]
}];

function createSelect($parent, list) {
    var $select = $('<select>');
    
    if ($parent.is('select')) {
        $select.insertAfter($parent);
    } else {
        $select.appendTo($parent);
    }
    
    $.each(list, function() {
        $('<option>')
            .data('children', this.children)
            .attr('value', this.value)
            .text(this.title || this.value)
            .appendTo($select);
    });
    
    $select.on('change', function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        var childList = $self.children('option:selected').data('children');
        $self.nextAll().remove();
        if (!childList) return;
        createSelect($self, childList);
    });
    
    $select.trigger('change');
}

function addNone(list) {
    list.unshift({ value: '-' });
    $.each(list, function() {
        if (!this.children) return;
        addNone(this.children);
    });
}

addNone(myList);

createSelect($('#selectGroup'), myList);
```

```css
select {
    margin: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: #5a5772;
    color:#fff;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 203px;
    height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selectGroup"></div>
```

Comment: @A1exandr, I think, you need to refactor now. As part of your existing architecture is very easy to make a bug, and too difficult to detect it.

Comment: I completely agree with you, the thing is that It's not my  project and I was just asked to ad js manipulations over `<select>` fields without any scope of data source.